# Update the ForceSimulation with new bubble radius

Tags: d3.js

I have initialised a bubble chart with force simulation. How do I update the data, ie. change the bubble radius.

I tried restarting the forceSimulation with a new set of nodes, but all the other nodes move as if the charge was increased.

```
var nodes=[{'radius':3},{'radius':4},{'radius':5},{'radius':6}];

var sim = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
    .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-1))
    .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
    .force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius(function(d) {
      return d.radius
    }))
    .on('tick',ticked)


 function ticked() {
  var u = svgContainer
     .selectAll('circle')
     .data(nodes)
   u.enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('fill','orange')
    .merge(u)
    .attr('r', function(d) {
    return d.radius
    })
   .attr('cx', function(d) {
      return d.x
    })
   .attr('cy', function(d) {
      return d.y
    })
  u.exit().remove()
}


function updateBubbles(){
    node[0]['radius]=10;
     sim.nodes(nodes).alpha(1).restart();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change updateBubbles to the following:

```
function updateBubbles() {
    svgContainer.selectAll('circle')
        .attr('r', 10);     
}
```

The nodes currently move as if charge was increased, because you're setting alpha to 1 and restarting the simulation. This is behavior we expect to see when we instantly reheat the graph.

Comment: When this happens, the force simulation is not applied